# Complex validation JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a validation where I first must check if a textbox contains valid data. If it doesn´t I will return an alertmessage and stop the post. If data is ok I will check if data is to be deleted and return a confirmation message to the user. If the user answer "Cancel" I will stop the post. If it´s a "OK" I will do the post. My code is not working.

```
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ValidateOCR",
            data: { strNumber: $('#OCR').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "False") {
                    bootbox.alert("Invalid data!")
                }
                else
                    if (data == True)
                    {
                        $("#hiddenButton").click();
                    }                       
            }
        });                    
    });

    $("#hiddenButton").click(function (event) {
        {
            var self = $(this);
            event.preventDefault();
            var selected = $("#ActionWrapper input:radio:checked").val();
            if (selected == 3) {

                bootbox.confirm("Are your sure you want to delete?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        self.unbind("click");
                        self.get(0).click();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (result == "True") {
                            $('#metadata').submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Just not working!! You should mention what problem or error are you facing.

Answer (score 0):

If #btnSubmit is a submit input, you need to capture the form submit event, not the button click event.

Use jquery to select the form and attach a submit event handler

```
$('form').submit(function(event)) { } //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I changed to:

                 $('form').submit(function(event)) { } //...

But still no sucess. I changed the code in the way that I validate my radiobutton on click on the radiobutton and the I do the validate on the submit. In that way the code works. Not the best solution but acceptable.